# Alternative Lockscreen with Fingerprints

Tags: lock-screens, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Is there a way to use the fingerprint sensor on my Samsung Galaxy s6 with a costum lockscreen like AcDisplay(no root)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Screenshot]You can use it on CM Locker. They said. And it will be compatible to S5 next month, but it's supported by S6.